# I need to calculate $P(A(50-T)\geq9)$, with $T\sim\exp(2)$ and $A\sim\exp(1)$ and $T$ and $A$ are independent.

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods

So I need to calculate $P(A(50-T)\geq9)$, with $T\sim\exp(2)$ and $A\sim\exp(1)$ and $T$ and $A$ are independent.

Also for integrating the lower limit can't be below zero. I think I found the joint density function of T and A,

$$f_{A,T}(x_{1},x_{2})=2e^{-x-2y}.$$

However now I'm stuck as I don't know what to do next.
Also the excersise states that if this problem isn't analytically solvable, show how it's done numerically.

I would really like to know how to continue solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to condition on $T$. (Note that, because $A\ge0$ a.s., the inequality $A(50-T)\ge9$ implies that $T<50$ a.s.)
$$P\Bigl(A(50-T)\ge 9\:\Big|\:T\Bigr)=\mathbf1_{\{T<50\}}\,P\!\left(A\ge\frac 9{50-T}\:\middle|\:T\right)=\mathbf1_{\{T<50\}}\exp\!\left(-\frac{9}{50-T}\right)\!=:f(T).$$
Now, by the [tower property/law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation),
\begin{align*}P\Bigl(A(50-T)\ge 9\Bigr)&=E\,f(T)\\[.4em]&=\int_0^{50}2\mathrm{e}^{-2t-\frac9{50-t}}\,\mathrm dt\\[.4em]&\approx0.8337\ldots\end{align*}

Comment: ah okee I see thank you. I just don't completely get how the tower property is used. would you mind writing this out for me?

Comment: @101010 $P(\mathrm{Event})=E[\mathbf1_{\mathrm{Event}}]=E\bigl[E[\mathbf1_{\mathrm{Event}}\mid T]\bigr]=E\bigl[P(\mathrm{Event}\mid T)\bigr]$ where $\mathrm{Event}=\{A(50-T)\ge9\}$.